# FFmpeg with node.js. Transcode a file to another format

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, transcode

Have a bit of a problem with this, I have an .avi file in which I would like to transcode into a .flv file using FFmpeg, here is what I have so far:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

//make sure you set the correct path to your video file
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'C:/Users/Jay/Documents/movie/drop.avi', nolog: true })

//Set the path to where FFmpeg is installed
.setFfmpegPath("C:\Users\Jay\Documents\FFMPEG")

//set the size
.withSize('50%')

// set fps
.withFps(24)

// set output format to force
.toFormat('flv')

// setup event handlers
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('file has been converted successfully');
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
})
// save to file <-- the new file I want -->
.saveToFile('C:/Users/Jay/Documents/movie/drop.flv');
```

It seems straightforward enough and I can do it through the FFmpeg command line, but I am trying to get it working within a node.js app, here is the error it is returning:

```
C:\Users\Jay\workspace\FFMPEGtest\test.js:17
.withSize('50%')
 ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'withSize' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jay\workspace\FFMPEGtest\test.js:17:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

It throws the same error for each built in FFmpeg function (.toFormat, .withFPS etc)

If anyone has a solution to this, I'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setFfmpegPath()` doesn't return an instance of `this`, as seen in the source [here.](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/70d469a18a92fd2d32ae624f491876f39e77ecf0/lib/capabilities.js#L25)
Meaning you can't chain the method.

Change it to

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

//make sure you set the correct path to your video file
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'C:/Users/Jay/Documents/movie/drop.avi', nolog: true })

//Set the path to where FFmpeg is installed
proc.setFfmpegPath("C:\\Users\\Jay\\Documents\\FFMPEG")

proc
//set the size
.withSize('50%')

// set fps
.withFps(24)

// set output format to force
.toFormat('flv')

// setup event handlers
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('file has been converted successfully');
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
})
// save to file <-- the new file I want -->
.saveToFile('C:/Users/Jay/Documents/movie/drop.flv');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that hasn't seemed to change anything though unfortunately, it's throwing the exact same error.

Comment: Thanks very much, just one more question, sorry now, it's not throwing that error any more but it is returning this line...: an error happened: cannot get available formats: spawn ENOENT. Any ideas on what that might be?

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped with another backslash.